# Generate regtest blocks with Bitcoin-Qt

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest, bitcoin-qt-setup

I'm prepping for a tabconf workshop and trying to make the simplest uX for workshop attendees.

Using bitcoincore.org for binaries: The Mac dmg doesn't come with a `bitcoin-cli` like with Linux. It does come with Bitcoin-Qt + console though which I'm guessing is good enough.

Is it possible to generate regtest blocks through the Bitcoin-Qt console GUI?
When I try to run `generate` I'll see:

```
has been replaced by the -generate cli option. Refer to -help for more information.
 (code -1)
```

It's not clear to me if I can utilize `-generate` through the gui console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access `-generate` from the Qt console. It's a feature inside `bitcoin-cli` only.

Note however that all `-generate` does is invoke the `getnewaddress` RPC to get a new address, and then invoke `generatetoaddress` to generate coins to it. You can do that directly by hand from the RPC console just fine.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Pieter, followup question. Is there a reason `generate` isn't available through Bitcoin-Qt or why it was taken out? I'm wondering if this would be an opportunity for me to look into enabling it or doing a feature request.

Comment: The history is that the `generate` RPC was removed, because it was mixing subsystems that were being disentangled (the wallet, and the mining logic). Instead there is just a `generatetoaddress` which mines to a given address, and a thin wrapper `-generate` in the CLI that just calls `getnewaddress` + `generatetoaddress`, to avoid too much breakage of tests relying on `generate`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Can you convert this to the answer^?